# What Type of Mushroom is this?

Tags: species-identification, mycology, mushroom

[image: Mushroom from yard]

Recently in Eastern Pennsylvania, there has been lots of rain and heat (90's) for a couple weeks now, so lots of mushrooms are popping up.

A neighbor posted a picture of this fungus in a community group, and was wondering if it is edible.

Comment: I found some images of Amanita rhopalopus that look similar, but I`m not totally convinced they are the same, as some look a bit different. Any one think they are Amanita rhopalopus?

Comment: You should not eat it if you don't know for certain what it is! E.g. here is a similar deadly mushroom: https://www.google.hu/search?q=gyilkos+gal%C3%B3ca&client=firefox-b-ab&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOgqreh57OAhVB3SwKHYyqBDoQ_AUICCgB&biw=1536&bih=730#imgrc=nrVy5g6yIBrD-M%3A

Comment: Obviously no one should eat any unidentified organism without the guidance of an expert. Thanks for the possibility.

Comment: Mushroom identification is very difficult. As well, post more detailed pictures, including gills and dissected views. **Do not ever imagine about eating an unknown fungus identified via web this way**. Experts identify mushrooms after collecting a lots of characteristics (including light-microscopy of tissue, spores etc and chemical tests at least), and also there is role of expertise of that experts. Tribal and Rural-peoples when collect mushroom, they very well-know the look ,habit and habitat of mushrooms they eat. Often, they collect fungus from a well-known site or locality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am no mycologist, but I think it looks like the false death cap, [*Amanita citrina*](http://www.naturephoto-cz.com/false-death-cap-photo-14967.html) *var. alba.*

I'm basing this mostly on color, size, and the universal veil remnants on the cap.  Here is a picture for comparison:

[image]

> Amanita citrina is now known to contain the toxin alpha-amanitin;
>   however, if eaten in normal amounts it is considered the concentration
>   is so low that it is unlikely to have any significant effect on a
>   healthy adult. Of far greater risk is the possibility of confusion
>   with one of the deadly Amanita species such as the Deathcap, *Amanita
>   phalloides*, or the Destroying Angel, *Amanita virosa*. For this reason
>   our advice is not to eat Amanita citrina, whether it is raw or cooked

Source: [First-Nature](http://www.first-nature.com/fungi/amanita-citrina.php)

Comment: It could be an *Amenita*, another option is a *Lepiota*.

Answer (score -2):

yes amanita sp. do not eat it at all. They come up in the grass after rain and hot weather.

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide a more detailed response, which may include an image of your proposed ID, organism distribution, and/or any other general background info that's relevant to the OP. +1 if you can do this.